# Create GeoTIFF from TIFF with Java

Tags: geotiff-tiff, jai

I create a tiff file from a bufferedImage in Java. I have some GCP (Ground Control Points) and I would like to make a GeoTiff. I know the GeoTIFF jai but this library is not updated since 2001...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno about using java, but you can use the gdal library :

[see here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html)

Comment: It's a java api ?

Comment: see https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava